# error while building a Hello World wxwidgets app with visual studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, wxwidgets

I'm trying build wxwidgets Hello World sample program in visual studio and i'm using prebuilt wxwidgets instead download that and build it myself.

and after configuring visual studio project for wxwidgets i always facing with this error:

```
Error   C1083   Cannot open include file: '../../../lib/vc142_x64_dll/mswud/wx/setup.h': No such file or directory  wxwidgets_programming_cpp   C:\wxwidgets\include\msvc\wx\setup.h    140
```

where is the problem. I think i configured visual studio project in a wrong way. can you help me how to configure visual studio project for a regular wxwidgets app?

Comment: same q for vs2017 https://stackoverflow.com/q/48027403/4117728

Comment: The error seems to be related to relative path that does not exist on your system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define `wxMSVC_VERSION_ABI_COMPAT` in the preprocessor definitions to use these binaries, which will result in using the correct `vc14x` prefix instead of `vc142` used by default. This is already supposed to be done by `wxwidgets.props`, at least for the DLL configuration which you seem to use, so I am not sure why it doesn't work for you if you do use this file, but at any rate this symbol must be defined and it isn't in your case.